# Partial fraction failure for $\frac{1}{\sin(x-a)\sin(x-b)}$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification, partial-fractions

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3047457/515527) in this answer I have tried to perform partial fraction for $\frac{1}{\sin(x-a)\sin(x-b)}$ as follows:
$$\frac{1}{\sin(x-a)\sin(x-b)}=\frac{p}{\sin(x-a)}+\frac{q}{\sin(x-b)} \quad(1)$$
Multiplying $(1)$ by $\sin(x-a)$ and plugging $x=a$ yields:
$$\left(\frac{1}{\sin(x-b)}=p+q\underset{\rightarrow 0}{\frac{\sin(x-a)}{\sin(x-b)}}\right)\bigg|_{x=a}\Rightarrow p=\frac{1}{\sin(a-b)}$$
Also to obtain q, multiply $(1)$ by $\sin(x-b)$ and plugg $x=b$ gives:
$$\left(\frac{1}{\sin(x-a)}=p\underset{\rightarrow 0}{\frac{\sin(x-b)}{\sin(x-a)}}+q\right)\bigg|_{x=b}\Rightarrow q=\frac{1}{\sin(b-a)}=-p$$
So that means we can rewrite the original expression as: $$\frac{1}{\sin(x-a)\sin(x-b)}=\frac{1}{\sin\left(a-b\right)}\left(\frac{1}{\sin\left(x-a\right)}-\frac{1}{\sin\left(x-b\right)}\right)$$
However as pointed out in the comments this doesn't verify. Can anyone point out where I went sideways with this?

Also the same approach can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882536/evaluation-of-i-int-frac1-sin-x-a-sinx-b-sinx-c-dx). Is there a rigurous way to prove that we can't perform partial fraction in this case?

Further question, what a about a general case such as proving/disproving: $${\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sin(x-x_k)}}\neq\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{\sin(x-x_k)}$$

Comment: Write $$\sin(a-b)=\sin\{x-b-(x-a)\}=?$$

Comment: What's the goal here?  To find constants $p,q$ that make (1) hold?  But perhaps there are no such constants.

Comment: Still doesn't add up... // Sure, so that we can evaluate the integral afterwards, but you're probably right, I haven't thought that we can't find such $p$ and $q$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is really happening is that $x\mapsto\sin(x-x_k)$ is a rational function of $\exp(ix)$, so $\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sin(x-x_k)}$ has a partial fraction decomposition of the form
\begin{align*}
\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sin(x-x_k)}
&=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2i\exp(-ix_k)\exp(ix)}{[\exp(ix)]^2-[\exp(ix_k)]^2}
\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{\alpha^-_k}{\exp(ix)+\exp(ix_k)}+\frac{\alpha^+_k}{\exp(ix)-\exp(ix_k)}\right)
\end{align*}
with $\alpha_k^\pm\in\mathbb{C}$.  To be able to say
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sin(x-x_k)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{\sin(x-x_k)}
$$
is thus the condition $\alpha_k^+=\alpha_k^-$ which we can check holds if and only if $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is there are no constants $p,\,q$ satisfying the intended identity. The reason $\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)}=\frac{p}{x-a}+\frac{q}{x-b}$ works is because the denominators are degree-$1$ polynomials, allowing the numerators to be degree-$0$. More generally distinct functions $f,\,g$ give $\frac{1}{fg}=\frac{p}{f}+\frac{q}{g}$ with *functions* $p=\frac{1}{g-f},\,q=-p$, among other options. But usually there isn't a solution with *constant* $p,\,q$.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a direct way to prove that there isn't a solution?

Comment: @Zacky You've effectively already found it. Your calculation uniquely determined what $p,\,q$ could be if they were constant, but we can verify it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please take a look here too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882536/evaluation-of-i-int-frac1-sin-x-a-sinx-b-sinx-c-dx that is invalid too right?

Comment: @Zacky I can't find a numerical counterexample to that, even with a computer search. I think the result is correct, even though the method of finding it needs more justification. Why does it only work with three sines, not two? Probably because the coefficients' ratios depend on $a,\,b,\,c$ in the three-sines case.

Answer (score 1):

We actually have
$$\frac1{\sin(x-a)\sin(x-b)} = \frac1{\sin(x-b)-\sin(x-a)}\left(\frac1{\sin(x-a)}-\frac1{\sin(x-b)}\right)$$
That factor of $\sin(x-b)-\sin(x-a)$ is equal to $\sin(a-b)$ at $a$ and at $b$, but not everywhere; it isn't constant.

Partial fractions are a theorem of linear algebra. If the factors we're dealing with aren't linear or at least polynomial, the theorem isn't valid. There is no partial fraction expansion of the type you're looking for here.